# Bind input field to freshslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I need to bind input field data to freshslider but am unable to do it.This is what i have

```
var max_price = $("#max_price").val();  // 0
var min_price = $("#min_price").val();  //4000
var range_slider =$("#ranged-value").freshslider({
    range: true,
    step:1,
    min:0,
    max: parseInt(max_price),
    values:[min_price,max_price],
    onchange:function(low, high){
        $("#minimum_price").val(low);
        $("#maximum_price").val(high);
    }
});
```

The above slider is working just perfectly but main problem arises when i want to bind input value of textfield to this slider i.e.

```
$("#maximum_price").change(function(){
    var value2 = parseInt($("#maximum_price").val());  // 400
    range_slider.freshslider("values",0,value2);
});
```

What happens is : whatever value i type in #maximum_price(input type text field) ,it would show only 50(1 value) in slider whereas i defined 2 range value initially.
I have tried all methods present in JQuery.slider API but i guess freshslider have different syntax for binding.

Thanks in Advance

Picture of result when input field is entered
[image]